# ADB in android studio says device offline

Tags: android, adb

But if I close android studio, ADB works normally. Device is Doogee X5 running android 6.0 without root

Comment: try to stop adb process  from task manager then start the  android studio. because maybe you have two adb .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Settings` -> `Developer option` -> `uncheck USB debugging` -> `check` it again.

Answer (score 2):

One of the likely culprits on this error is to blame Android SDK which has frequent updates and the one on your active path has not been fully updated between adb client and server.

To work around this problem, do the following ==>

0: replug in the phone and connect as either as "File transfers" or "Photo transfer (PTP); default is "Charging". 
On Nexus 6, you can make that change by opening the notification "USB for ...."

1: On your PC, go to the folder where the latest Android SDK tool folder is. For example, on Windows 7, it should be somewhere like:
C:\Users\xxx_yyy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\

2: go that folder, type "adb devices"